# Map comma seperated values in two columns in Excel

Tags: excel, macros

I have an excel with two Columns. ColA and ColB.

There are comma seperated values in each of the Columns.
I need each of the values in ColA to be mapped to each of the value in ColB.

Sample Data:

```
ColA      ColB
A,B,C     4,5
E,F       6,8,3
```

Expected Output

```
A 4
A 5
B 4
B 5
C 4
C 5
E 6
E 8
E 3
F 6
F 8
F 3
```

Can I do this with a Macro?

Comment: Yes this can be done with vba.  In answer to your follow up question, Stack Overflow is not a code for me service nor is it a point me in the right direction site.  Please attempt on your own and come back with the code when it does not work and we will help you with specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have a play with arrays, I don't know where the data should end up so you will have to play around, but should get you started.

```
Dim strTest As String, strArray() As String
Dim strTest2 As String, strArray2() As String
Dim intCount As Integer, intCount2 As Integer
Dim colCount As Integer, i As Integer

colCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To colCount
    strTest = Cells(i, 1).Value
    strArray = Split(strTest, ",")
    strTest2 = Cells(i, 2).Value
    strArray2 = Split(strTest, ",")

    For intCount = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
         For intCount2 = LBound(strArray2) To UBound(strArray2)
             Debug.Print Trim(strArray(intCount) & "," & strArray2(intCount2))
         Next
    Next
Next i
```